# boost::lock_guard waits forever

Tags: c++, boost, locking, deadlock, boost-mutex

I'm developing a LRU-cache in C++, using boost mutexes and locks, in a multi-threaded environment.
The architecture is based on a boost::unordered_map + a [lock-free-queue](http://haxpath.squarespace.com/imported-20100930232226/2010/8/25/a-lock-free-queue-in-c.html)
Insertions work in non-blocking mode (try_lock), but removals should lock the map and proceed.
The problem is that very rarely, the cache-access deadlocks in the removal.

.h

```
typedef boost::function<std::string ( const std::string &key )> LoaderFunction;

class ListNode;

struct CacheEntry {
    CacheEntry(std::string key="", std::string value="");
    ListNode * createLruListNode() const;
    ListNode * getLruListNode() const;
    virtual ~CacheEntry();
    const std::string key;
    const std::string value;
private:
    ListNode ** listNodePP;
};

struct ListNode {
    ListNode(const CacheEntry* entry = NULL);
    ~ListNode();
    void setCacheEntry(const CacheEntry* entry);
    const CacheEntry * getCacheEntry();
    void setDirty();

private:
    const CacheEntry * cacheEntry;
    bool dirty;
};

typedef LockFreeQueue<ListNode*> List;


typedef boost::unordered_map
        < const string               , const CacheEntry * >
Cache;

typedef Cache::iterator CacheIter;
```

.cpp

```
#include "LockFreeQueue.h"
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

/* ... */

ListNode::ListNode(const CacheEntry* e2) : cacheEntry(e2) {
    dirty=false;
}

void ListNode::setCacheEntry(const CacheEntry* entry) {
    cacheEntry=entry;
}

const CacheEntry* ListNode::getCacheEntry() {
    if(dirty) {
        return NULL;
    }
    return cacheEntry;
}

void ListNode::setDirty() {
    dirty=true;
}

std::string PeachCachePartition::get(const string key) {
    CacheIter iter=cache->find(key);
    string value;
    if(iter!=cache->end()) { 
        __sync_fetch_and_add(_hits,1);
        const CacheEntry* entry=iter->second;
        value=(entry->value);

        lruList->enqueue(entry->getLruListNode());
        if(size() > max) { // removes some
            int howMany = (int) ceil((*_misses)/(*_hits))+1;
            int k=0;
            ListNode removedListNode=ListNode();
            ListNode * p=&removedListNode;
            ListNode ** pp=&p;
            while(size() > max && k<howMany) {

                if(lruList->dequeue(pp)) {
                    const CacheEntry * toBeRemoved=p->getCacheEntry();
                    if(toBeRemoved) {
                        remove(toBeRemoved->key);
                        k++;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    } else { 
        __sync_fetch_and_add(_misses,1);
        value=loader(key);
        if(value.size()>0) {
            put(key,value);
        }
    }
    return value;
}

void PeachCachePartition::remove(const std::string &key) {
    try {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> mapLockGuard(mapMutex);
        CacheIter iter = cache->find(key);
        if(iter!=cache->end()) {
            const CacheEntry * toBeRemoved=iter->second;
            if(toBeRemoved->getLruListNode()) {
                toBeRemoved->getLruListNode()->setDirty();
            }

            delete(toBeRemoved);
            cache->erase(iter);
            __sync_sub_and_fetch(_size,1);
        }
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        Logger::err(e.what());
    }
}


void PeachCachePartition::put(const std::string &key, std::string &value) {
    try {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> mapLockGuard(mapMutex,boost::try_to_lock);
        if(mapLockGuard.owns_lock()) {
            CacheIter iter=cache->find(key);
            const CacheEntry * entry;
            if(iter!=cache->end()) {
                entry=iter->second;
                entry->getLruListNode()->setDirty();
            } else {
                entry = new CacheEntry(key,value);
                __sync_add_and_fetch(_size,1);
                (*cache)[key] = entry;
            }

            entry->createLruListNode()->setCacheEntry(entry);

            lruList->enqueue(entry->getLruListNode());
        }
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        Logger::err(e.what());
    }
}
```

Can you explain me what's wrong? I'm almost sure it deadlocks in the removal as it is the only lock it *must* acquire.

Thanks everybody

edit: I'm using this cache in an apache module which runs mpm_prefork_module: could this be the problem? Should I use boost::interprocess instead of boost::thread?

Comment: This lacks code. To decently be sure where the deadlock is we need all function bodies that you call within put and remove. Most likely in some code path put will call remove or vice-versa.

Comment: You mean: the LoaderFunction? It simply calls an external service and get the xml as string.